# Replace text on enter input field

Tags: jquery, input

So I basically have this input field that popups once text is clicked. And I want the text that I type in the input field to replace the original text, seems simple enough but I'm lost here...

**JQuery:**

```
$('.profile-brief').click(function () {
         $(this).click(function (e) {
             var statusBio = $('#status').val();
             $(this).replaceWith('<form><input id="status" type="text"></input></form>');
             if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                 console.log(statusBio);
                 $(this).html('<form><input id="status" type="text">' + statusBio + '</input></form>');
             }
         });
     });
```

Here's the
http://jsfiddle.net/0beocw0o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code in jsfiddle

```
  $('.profile-brief').on('click',function(e){
       var textbox = document.createElement('input');
       textbox.type = 'text';
       textbox.id = 'status';
       $('.profile-brief').html(textbox);
       $('.profile-brief').off();
       $('#status').on('keypress',function(e){
          if(e.keyCode === 13){
             $('.profile-brief').html($('#status').val());
          }
       });
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0beocw0o/1/

Comment: How can I get it to allow the text to be edited multiple times?

Comment: Using hide and show solves this proble for multiple times here is link for that http://jsfiddle.net/0beocw0o/6/

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do:

```
$('.profile-brief').click(function (e) {
        var txt=$(this).text(); 
        $(this).hide();
        var inputbox=$('#status');                 
        inputbox.val(txt);
        inputbox.show();
        inputbox.focus();

    });

$('#status').keypress(function(e){
    console.log(e.which);
    if(e.which == 13){
       var txt=$(this).val();
        $(this).hide();
        $('.profile-brief').text(txt);
        $('.profile-brief').show();
    }
});
```

it is better to put key event listener outside of onclick event listener and you have two click handlers, that's reason your click event is working after the second click.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0beocw0o/3/

Comment: Note that the jQuery method `.focus()` does _not_ focus an element. It is an event listener binding method, similar to `.click()`. What you want is the DOM element method. So something like `inputbox[0].focus()`.

Comment: afaik, It delegates and triggers inputbox.focus() which puts cursor into the input box..

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of it; not sure why you want to add an input on keypress but you can try. This'll work for everytime you click profile-brief

```
$('.profile-brief').click(function () {
    $(this).toggle();
    $("#status").toggle();
    $("#status").focus();
})


$('#status').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        var statusBio = $('#status').val();
        $(".profile-brief").html(statusBio);
    //$(".profile-brief").html('<form><input id="status2" type="text"></input></form>');
    //$("#status2").val(statusBio);
    $(".profile-brief").toggle();
    $("#status").toggle();
}
```

})

http://jsfiddle.net/0beocw0o/4/

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers work assuming you only need one of these "editable div's" on a page, because they update the text of every "profile-brief" element. This version is pure JQuery and works independently for each element you select.

http://jsfiddle.net/0beocw0o/5/

```
function fnEditableText(e) {
    $(this).unbind('click')
    .html('<input id="status" type="text"/>');

    $(this).find('#status').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            var objTxt = $(this).parent();
            objTxt.html($(this).val());
            objTxt.click(fnEditableText);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.profile-brief').click(fnEditableText);
});
```